# Adding attributes from nested object on XmlElement

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have following code

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class SeatDescriptor {

  String id;
  Seat seat;

  @XmlAttribute
  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @XmlElement
  public Seat getSeat() {
    return seat;
  }
  public void setSeat(Seat seat) {
    this.seat = seat;
  }
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Seat {
  int number;

  @XmlAttribute
  public int getNumber() {
    return number;
  }

  public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
  }
}
```

The code generates following kind of XML

```
<seatdesc id="ii">
        <seat number="20"/>
    </seatdesc>
```

What I want is to have attributes from Seat object on `seatdesc` tag. How can I do that?

```
<seatdesc id="ii"  number="20" />
```

Comment: I never used myself, but this link look promising: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html  (look the part: Using MOXy to Map Two Objects to the Same Node)

Comment: Can you modify your classes? or not?

Comment: @Xstian that would be the last option for me. will add getter methods accordingly

Comment: @fluminis I tried using `@XmlPath` but not able to achieve it. Can you please let me know how

Comment: just observed that `@XmlAttribute` not working with `@XmlPaths` for multiple classes. Submitted another question for it. Once it works out, Moxy would be the way to go for me. Will update